# how do i remove hdri image from reflections. [Image added]

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri, reflection

I want to keep the reflections from other meshes but remove the hdri image from reflecting. I just want to use the hdri for lighting. image shows what I want showing and not. green good red bad.
using version 2.93.1
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this node setup for your world: Mix your HDRI with the color (or other HDRI) you want to see as reflexion, and use an *Input > Light Paht > Is Glossy Ray* as factor of your *Mix Shade*r:

[image]

If you don't want to see the HDRI as background either, I guess you need to mix your *Mix Shader* with another one and this time use the *Is Camera Ray* output. But it looks like you've enabled the film *Transparent* option.

Comment: Thank you moon!