# My cycles render gives the wall unusual black dots and glasses reflects the HDRI image?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I render my images in cycles , the walls get an  unusual shading like black dots( are those noises?)  and also my glass reflects the Hdri image

How can i correct this?[image]

Comment: for glass you can check out this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248852/how-do-i-remove-hdri-image-from-reflections-image-added

Comment: Yes, the "black spots" look indicative of over-aggressive de-noising in what would otherwise be a noisy area. Try increasing your sample count and if necessary, increase the number of diffuse bounces.